# Is it possible to export top level Opaque Types in Scala 3?

Tags: scala, scala-3, opaque-types

I am playing with the Scala 3 feature [Export Clauses](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/export.html).

Everything works, except of *opaque types*.

I could not find any restrictions on them.
My Opaque Type:

```
opaque type BpmnPath = String

object BpmnPath:
  def apply(path: String): BpmnPath = path
```

My exports:

```
package camundala

export model.BpmnPath
```

Usage:

```
package camundala
package dsl

trait DSL :

  def path(pathStr: String): BpmnPath =
    BpmnPath(pathStr)
```

This gives me the following exception:

```
Found:    camundala.model.exports$package.BpmnPath
Required: camundala.BpmnPath²

where:    BpmnPath  is a type in package object exports$package
          BpmnPath² is a type in package object exports$package which is an alias of camundala.model.BpmnPath
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this question on the [Scala Contributor Forum](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/is-it-possible-to-export-top-level-opaque-types-in-scala-3/5136).

Turns out that this is a bug that is fixed with `3.0.1-RC1`.